# SliverAppBar is not working even after adding expanded widget

Tags: flutter

What's the correct way to make a collapsible header in flutter?

I tried the following but it didn't work. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

```
return CustomScrollView(
  shrinkWrap: true,
  slivers: [
    SliverAppBar(
      expandedHeight: 200,
      pinned: true,
      flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
        title: Text(title),
        background: Image(image: AssetImage(imgPath), fit: BoxFit.cover),
      ),
    ),
    SliverFillRemaining(
      child: Column(
        children: [Text('some cool text here')],
      ),
    )
  ],
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's a correct way and it works healthy. If you are asking why its not completely collapsing, you should check "pinned" value. If you set it "false" it will completely collapse.

```
  SliverAppBar(
   expandedHeight: 200,
   pinned: false,
   flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
    title: Text(title),
    background: Image(image: AssetImage(imgPath), fit: BoxFit.cover),
   ),
  ),
```

You can check [this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliverAppBar-class.html) documentation for further information about SliverAppBar.